# Saving an image (jpg) on a remote server without local hard disk

Tags: c, linux, ftp, jpeg, gdk

I have a linux app programmed in C which uses gdk for image stuff. The images are sent to a remote server through FTP (with libcurl).

Currently I'm saving the images first to a local hard disk with gdk_pixbuf_save, but this seems kinda useless step. How difficult would it be to save the images directly on the remote server? I would also need to use the quality setting of jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`gdk_pixbuf_save_to_buffer`](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-file-saving.html#gdk-pixbuf-save-to-buffer) that can store data to a `gchar` buffer.

I wasn't able to quickly find the CURL API associated with FTP `put` requests; hopefully you'll be familiar enough with CURL to know how to `put` a file using a buffer as contents.

Comment: Now I was finally able to test this and I ran into a following problem: how do I properly allocate memory for the gchar buffer gdk_pixbuf_save_to_buffer uses, as I don't think I know beforehand how big the resulting jpg will be? I'm also not very familiar with memory management in C.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the question about memory allocation; if you want to add a new answer with the details on memory allocation and curl API, that'd be superb, so someone else with a similar question in the future can save the time.

Comment: I actually made [completely another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453996/sending-an-image-to-ftp-server-from-gchar-buffer-libcurl) because i had a bigger problem with the CURL callback function, and there is a great answer given to it.